# Как создать из двух или более массивов-списков один многомерный массив

Tags: python, массивы

На вход я получаю несколько массивов(всегда одномерных).

```
b = [-1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
```

После должен получить:

```
d = [[-1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Решение должно быть универсальным, на вход буду получать от одного до 5 массивов.

Comment: какие проблемы у вас с кодом? вы знаете метод list.append() ?

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1]
b=[2]

c=[]
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
c #[[1],[2]]
```

Создаём пустой список и добавляем в него списки как элементы

````
alef=['a']
bet=['b']
...
с=[alef,bet,gimel,dalet,echo,fi]```
c #[['a'],['b'],['c'],...]
````

Второй вариант, как видно много проще, то есть в ручную создаётся итоговый список. Из недостатков- нужно в ручную писать все имена переменных, из достоинств имена переменных могут быть безсистемны

```
a='a'
b='b'
...
z='z'
itog=[]
for it in range(97,26): #97 начало мелкой латиницы в таблице ascii, 26- максимальное кол-во добавляемых переменных
   itog.append(eval(chr(it)))
```

Данный пример добавляет в итоговый список до 26 переменных, имена которых есть латинские буквы в нижнем регистре. Имеет следующие недостатки: пропускать переменные в данном виде нельзя так как будет исключение.

Comment: А если дано 5 или 10 массивов? Будем 10 раз писать `append`?

Comment: можно циклом, либо eval'ом, проблемма в том, что нужно откуда-то брать имена переменных, сча обновлю код.

Answer (score 1):

Не скажу, что это на 100% универсальное решение, но можно и так:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [-1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]

list_2d = lambda *lists: [l for l in lists]
d = list_2d(a,b,c)

print(f'{d = }')  # d = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [-1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое и короткое решение:

```
b = [-1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
d=[b, c]
# d=[[-1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Большое преимущество: почти при любом количестве массивов можно уложиться в одну строку, просто перечислив имена массивов через запятую. А у ответа, который сказал @ganz, придётся делать столько строк с `append`-ами...